# Find $\delta$ when $\epsilon$ is known (limit problem)

Tags: calculus, limits

I had a wicked time of these limit problems on a quiz, I can't find any examples of this with the $x$ in the denominator. How do you establish the connection between $|x – 1|$ and $|f(x) – 1|$?

Find the largest $\delta$ such that if $0 < |x – 1| < \delta $, then $|f(x) – 1| < 0.1$.

$f(x) = 2 - \frac{1}{x}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Hint:***

$$ |f(x) - 1| = |  \frac 1 x - 1| \lt 0.1 \iff \frac 1 x \in (0.9, 1.1) \iff 0.9 \lt \frac 1 x \lt 1.1$$

Comment: Then we get $\frac{1}{9} > x - 1 > \frac{-1}{11}$. I know it is right but the answer is $\delta = \frac{1}{11}$. So why $\frac{1}{11}$ and not $\frac{1}{9}$?

Comment: Because $1/9$ would give you the interval $-1/9 \lt x-1\lt 1/9$. Parts of this fall outside $-1/11\lt x-1\lt 1/9$.

Comment: Hint: "Largest $\delta$..", and **both** inequalities $ x - 1 \lt \frac 1 9 $ ** and ** $ x - 1 \gt \frac{-1}{11} $ must be satisfied  for $\frac 1 x$ to be in the given range. Note that $y \gt \frac {-1}{9}$ does not imply that $y \gt \frac {-1}{11}$

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing down what $|f(x) - 1| < 0.1$ means and then solve for a range of $x$.

$|f(x)-1| < 0.1$

$-0.1 < f(x)-1 < 0.1$

$0.9 < f(x) < 1.1$

$0.9 < 2-\dfrac{1}{x} < 1.1$

Can you find a range for $x$ that makes this true? That will help you determine what $\delta$ needs to be.